# Java Split string into array, by size and only split after delimiters

Tags: java, arrays, string, split

I have a many string wich are really randomly sized like : 5 chars to 12000 randomly.

Eg:

```
String 1 : A,b,C,d
String 2 :23,343,342,4535,4535,453,234,
String 3 : ,asdsfdfdasgfdsfsf,dsfdsfdsfdsfsdfdf,sdsfdsfdsfsdf, <- and this around another 1000 times.
```

I want to upload them to my database by their ID. So my problem is that the oracle database varchar can conatians only 4k bytes.

**Edit:**
So if the string bigger than 4k. I want a String[] where each element maximum 4000k characters lets count 3900. ( And ofc if i go throught the array I get back the same String, and each array element last "word" is a whole word not sliced)

So my idea is simply if the string.lenth <1000 then go.
else split it by ~4000 stocks but only split after coma.

My solution so far ( without coma care)

```
        for (My_type type: types) {
        String[] tokens =
                Iterables.toArray(
                    Splitter
                        .fixedLength(4000)
                        .split(type.area),
                    String.class
                );
```

how can I replace this function to get an "good array"?

Comment: can you explain 'else split it by ~4000 stocks' a bit.

Comment: Just checking: Do you literally mean "after a comma" - ie do you want to keep the comma at the end of a section?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think `split()` is an option. I think you need to use a Matcher to consume as much input as possible, then build a list of captured sections:

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(".{1,3999}(,|.$)").matcher(input);
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
while (matcher.find())
    list.add(matcher.group());
```

If you really want an array (not recommended)

```
String[] array = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
```

This regex is greedy and will consume up to 4000 chars that ends with a comma or the end of input. A length of 3999 is used to allow 1 more for the comma itself, and the dot before the end marker $ is to consume one more because $ is zero-width.

Comment: Thanks, I skip the array part. List is good for me. Thanks the advice also.

Answer (score 2):

This will give you such tokens, in a List<> - hoping that's fine.

```
for (My_type type: types) {
    String longString = type.area;
    List<String> tokens = new ArrayList<>();
    while (longString.length() > 4000) {
        int splitIndex = longString.lastIndexOf(",", 3999);
        if (splitIndex < 0) {
            // no comma found
            throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot split string");
        }
        tokens.add(longString.substring(0, splitIndex));
        longString = longString.substring(splitIndex + 1); // leaving out the comma
    }
    if (tokens.size() == 0) {
        tokens.add(longString);
    }
}
```